# interpolation in application causes sprite to jitter

Tags: sdl, interpolation, game-loop

I wanted to implement a special Game loop where the game actually only updates 25 frames a second while it is rendered at the top speed of the computer. I followed the article from dewitters game loop and have the interpolation setup correctly i believe (btw i'm using sdl2)...

```
const int TICKS_PER_SECOND = 25;
const int SKIP_TICKS = 1000 / TICKS_PER_SECOND;
const int MAX_FRAMESKIP = 5;

Uint32 next_game_tick = SDL_GetTicks();
int loops;
float interpolation;

while (running)
{
    loops = 0;
    while (SDL_GetTicks() > next_game_tick && loops < MAX_FRAMESKIP)
    {
        Update();

        next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS;
        loops++;
    }

    interpolation = float(SDL_GetTicks() + SKIP_TICKS - next_game_tick) / float(SKIP_TICKS);
    Render(interpolation);
}
```

But I don't really understand how to implement the interpolation within the render call. i tried just setting the x and y position of my sprite relative to the interpolation...

```
interPos.x = pos.x + int (speed * interpolation);
interPos.y = pos.y + int (speed * interpolation);
link.Draw(ren, interPos, 0, false);
```

but this just made the main character sprite jitter all around. Any help appreciated!